# How to disable FullPage.js on specific sections?

Tags: fullpage.js

I am using the excellent [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) library to create a fullscreen site, however I would like to disable the fullpage.js scrolling after the user reaches the second section and allow the user to scroll from then on as normal. Can't seem to find any clues in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

please, use this callback method:
afterLoad (origin, destination, direction)

```
afterLoad: function (origin, destination, direction) {
    var loadedSection = this;

    if (destination == 2) {
        alert("receive to Section 2");
    }
}
```

code snippet example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            scrollingSpeed: 300,
            sectionsColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],

            afterLoad: function (origin, destination, direction) {
                var loadedSection = this;

                if (destination == 2) {
                    alert("receive to Section 2");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
 .section {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 36px;
            color: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>

<div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section">section 1</div>
        <div class="section">section 2</div>
        <div class="section">section 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use the `scrollOverflow` option that simulates the normal scrolling within a section.

See [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).